# Null value of wrkBk.getSheetByName

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a few lines of code that have been written to send a mass, custom email to many recipients. I have a Google sheet titled "EmailList" with email addresses, and names of the recipients in one worksheet titled "Email_ID" and the custom email message in another worksheet titled "Mail_Details."

When I run my code, I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null (line 4, file "Code")" message.

The beginning of the code is as follows:

```
function sendMails() {

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var wrkShtEmail_ID= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Email_ID");

  var wrkShtMessage= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Mail_Details");
```

While I realize this is a fairly simple issue, I can't figure out where my disconnect is in my code. All of my sheet names are correctly spelled, and the script and sheet name is under the same Gmail account. How can I get "Email_ID" to not show up as a null value?

Complete code as follows, if needed:

```
    function sendMails() {

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkShtEmail_ID= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Email_ID");
  var wrkShtMessage= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Mail_Details");

  var subject = wrkShtMessage.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var message = wrkShtMessage.getRange('B2').getValue();

  for (var i=2;i<=5;i++){

    var fname = wrkShtEmailIDs.getrange('A' + i).getvalue();
    var emailAddress = wrkShtEmailIDs.getRange ('B' + i).getValue();
    var companyname = wrkShtEmailIDs.getrange('C' + i).getValue();
    var finalmsg = "";
    finalmsg = "Hi " + fname + ","+ "\n" + message;
    finalmsg=finalmsg.replace("as the best person to contact at ","as the best person to contact at " + companyname + ".")
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,finalmsg);


  }

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet) says "Returns the currently active spreadsheet, or null if there is none." So the question is, why is there no active spreadsheet. Where and how is that code executed?

Comment: Ah, I think I have realized the problem now (along with a few other capitalization errors). I believe it was not linked directly through google sheets script editor, and instead just written through script.google.com. That took way too long to figure out, so your help is much appreciated! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If the script isn't bound to spreadsheet, **getActiveSpreadsheet()**  will return null. Use openById instead

var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_OF_RELATED_SHEET');